# How to run a hand coded TF network (no training)

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a small TF network where I have tried to initialize all the weights by hand. I am trying to give it a specific input (of all ones) and see what the network will generate. The reason I am doing it is that I am trying to reproduce a TF model in R and am having some differences and I would like to do a debug by trying to replicate a small model in TF and R and compare the results.

So, the input to the model is created as:

```
shape = (1, 3, 128, 64)
x = np.ones(shape).astype(np.float32)
x = np.transpose(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))  # Convert to NHWC
network = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The network is very simple where we have a:

```
Conv2d -> Batch Norm (BN) -> ELU activation -> Flatten -> Dense -> BN -> ELU
```

So, I create the network as follows:

```
# w is a numpy array with the shape in (NHWC) format
network = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=network, filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='SAME', use_bias=False,
                           trainable=False, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(w))


# Batch normalization (The initialization variables are numpy arrays)
network = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x=network, mean=tf.convert_to_tensor(m), variance=tf.convert_to_tensor(v),
                                    offset=tf.convert_to_tensor(b), scale=tf.convert_to_tensor(s), variance_epsilon=1e-8)

# Activation
network = tf.nn.elu(network)

# Flatten the network
network = tf.layers.flatten(network)

# Fully connected
network = tf.layers.dense(inputs=network, units=128, use_bias=False, trainable=False)

# Batch normalization
network = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x=network, mean=tf.convert_to_tensor(m), variance=tf.convert_to_tensor(v),
                                    offset=tf.convert_to_tensor(b), scale=tf.convert_to_tensor(s), variance_epsilon=1e-8)

out = tf.nn.elu(network)
```

I think I have created the network correctly. However, now I have no idea how to run this. The online examples that I have seen seem to train and tehn save the weights and reload the saved graph but I was wondering if there is an easy way to simply run the forward pass (I do not need to do any training and I have hard coded the weights) and get the 128 dimensional vector out, so that I can verify the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # to actually initialize variables
    results = sess.run(out)  # forward pass
```

`results` is now a numpy array containing the output of the network given the input you created in the first code block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the thing though... I have initialized the variables myself (I do not want random initialization) as I want to use the weights that I have supplied. So do I need to modify the first line? Also does it have some special flag to run in inference mode (Batch Norm would usually work differently in training vs inference)

Comment: trying this, I get an array of ones back which is not what I was expecting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really pay attention I guess. The initializer will "run" whatever intialization you supplied, so in this case it won't be random since you supplied constants.

Comment: Also note that you have a fully-connected layer where you specified no initializer, so it will have random weights.